# Android padding left animation in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-animation, android-relativelayout

I am trying  to create a padding left animation in RelativeLayout. I wrote code which can animate left in click listener.
This is my code, but it is not working completely.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            holder = (UserHolder) view.getTag();

            layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.layoutmain
                    .getLayoutParams();
            if (holder.layout.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {

                ValueAnimator varl = ValueAnimator.ofInt(-170);
                varl.setDuration(1000);

                varl.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {

                        layoutParams.setMargins(
                                (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue(), 0,
                                0, 0);
                        holder.layoutmain.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        holder.layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                });
                varl.start();

            }
            else
            {
                ValueAnimator varl = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0);
                varl.setDuration(1000);

                varl.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(
                            ValueAnimator animation) {

                        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0,
                                (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue(),
                                0);

                        // lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom)
                        holder.layoutmain.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                        holder.layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }
                });
                varl.start();
            }




        }

    });
```

The first time, it works (I can animate padding left), but the second time I click the animation is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Through ValueAnimator class you can update margin or padding of any with animation. Please go through the following code :

```
 ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0,50);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator){
            frameLayout.setPadding(0, (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue(),0,0);
        }
    });
    animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2));
    animator.start();
```

Let me know in case of more explanation in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using ValueAnimator.ofInt(fromInt,toInt)

```
//first    
ValueAnimator.ofInt(-70,0)

//second
ValueAnimator.ofInt(0,-70)
```

Otherwise the value animator doesn't know from or to which value it should animate.

Comment: i changed it but i can not animate holder.layout layout :(

Comment: why are you calling holder.layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE). Isn't your error comming from that ? what is the hierachy of your layouts ? does holder.layoutmain containt holder.layout ?